# "value is not a record or a record-id" when passing batch variable to "set =" in update

Tags: orientdb

**EDIT : see at bottom for reproduce the problem on a smaller stat/schema set**

I'm experimenting around OrientDB time-series use case and I'm trying to chain each levels of two trees. So I did this sql batch :

```
let $w1 = select expand(W1[2406]) from #12:2;
let $w2 = select expand(W1[2407]) from #12:2;
let $d1 = select expand(D1[4]) from $w1;
let $d2 = select expand(D1[0]) from $w2;
let $h1 = select expand(H1[23]) from $d1;
let $h2 = select expand(H1[0]) from $d2;
let $m1 = select expand(M1[59]) from $h1;
let $m2 = select expand(M1[0]) from $h2;
update $w1 set next = $w2;
update $w2 set previous = $w1;
update $d1 set next = $d2;
update $d2 set previous = $d1;
update $h1 set next = $h2;
update $h2 set previous = $h1;
update $m1 set next = $m2;
update $m2 set previous = $m1;
```

But I get this error on the first update:

```
The field 'W1.next' has been declared as LINK but the value is not a record or a record-id
```

...That I don't understand because when I try :

```
return [$w1, $w2, $d1, $d2, $h1, $h2, $m1, $m2];
```

I get the records as expected...

So two questions :

1. Why this error ?
2. Is there a better way to do this since I'm still a beginner ?

(Note : I would like to stay in sql/batch sql)

the classes are like this :

```
Symbol{
   W1 : LINKMAP W1
}

W1 {
   next : LINK W1
   previous : LINK W1
   D1 : LINKMAP D1
}
D1 {
   next : LINK D2
   previous : LINK D2
   H1 : LINKMAP H1
}
H1 [...]
M1 [...]
```

**EDIT : How to reproduce the problem on a smaller data set :**

Schema creation :

```
create class A extends V;
create class B extends V;
create property A.B LINKMAP B;
create property B.B LINK B;
```

note : A.B is an array-like of B elements, B.B is a 1to1 link

dummy values to insert :

```
insert into B CONTENT {}
insert into B CONTENT {}
```

now, get the rids of the two dummies to insert into A

```
select from B
```

now insert as follow the two items (`#13:0` and `#13:1` in my case)

```
insert into A(B) values ({'0' : #13:0, '1' : #13:1})
insert into A(B) values ({'0' : #13:0, '1' : #13:1})
```

Finally, try this batch :

```
let $b1 = select expand(B[0]) from A;
let $b2 = select expand(B[1]) from A;
update $b1 SET B = $b2;
update $b2 SET B = $b1;
```

you see the error

The field 'B.B' has been declared as LINK but the value is not a record or a record-id

but if you do that :

```
let $b1 = select expand(B[0]) from A;
let $b2 = select expand(B[1]) from A;
return $b1;
```

and

```
let $b1 = select expand(B[0]) from A;
let $b2 = select expand(B[1]) from A;
return $b2;
```

and

```
let $b1 = select expand(B[0]) from A;
let $b2 = select expand(B[1]) from A;
return {'b1': $b1, 'b2' : $b2};
```

you can see that they are not collections, but really records

**EDIT2 The solution provided by Isavio works, but I would like to know why it does since in the previous results, they doesn't seem to be collection?**

```
let $b1 = select expand(B[0]) from A;
let $b2 = select expand(B[1]) from A;
update $b1 SET B = $b2[0];
update $b2 SET B = $b1[0];
```

Comment: Hi, do you have a simple DB test to share ?

Comment: uh... yes, I think I can give you something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be possible that the result of update is a collection of records? Can you try using:

```
.....
update $w1 set next = $w2[0];
....
```

**EDIT**

I think using the LET will result always a collection.

Comment: The expand prevents it normally

Comment: That effectively works, but I'd like to know why to validate the answer ;) (I mean, why then with the `return {'b1': $b1, 'b2' : $b2};` it doesn't return a singleton collection ?