# Writing subqueries in orientDB

Tags: orientdb

This is the query i'm using right now :

```
INSERT INTO details SET name = "INITIALIZE",actionMap ={"1":12:1,"2":12:2};
```

Here 12:1,12:2 are rid's from another table.I'm facing a lot of problem's hardcoding these rid values.In order to avoid this i'd like to add the query like this

```
INSERT INTO details SET name = "INITIALIZE",actionMap ={"1":(select @rid from action where start is not null),"2":(select @rid from action where stop is not null)};
```

I'm getting this exception:

> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OValidationException: The
>   field 'details.actionMap' has been declared as LINKMAP but the
>   value is not a record or a record-id

So how can i change my query to help my case.

Comment: Is actionmap the name of the edge you are using?

Answer (score 2):

This indeed can be done in a more gracefull way using batches.

This is just to create the object you want

```
INSERT INTO details SET name = "INITIALIZE"
```

We will turn this into

```
let $inserted = INSERT INTO details SET name = "INITIALIZE"
```

And add the edges you would like to add:

```
CREATE EDGE actionMap FROM $inserted TO (SELECT FROM action WHERE start is not null )
CREATE EDGE actionMap FROM $inserted TO (SELECT FROM action WHERE stop is not null )
```

So the entire batch you would have to run is

```
let $inserted = INSERT INTO details SET name = "INITIALIZE"
CREATE EDGE actionMap FROM $inserted TO (SELECT FROM action WHERE start is not null )
CREATE EDGE actionMap FROM $inserted TO (SELECT FROM action WHERE stop is not null )
```

If you have any more questions about this feel free to ask.

Comment: Hi mitchen,I'm using the document api rather than the graph api

Comment: Oh in that case I will not be able to help you any further i guess, good luck finding the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35516022/value-is-not-a-record-or-a-record-id-when-passing-batch-variable-to-set-in)

```sql
let $a1 = SELECT FROM action WHERE start IS NOT null
let $a2 = SELECT FROM action WHERE stop IS NOT null
INSERT INTO details SET name = "INITIALIZE", actionMap = {"1": $a1[0], "2": $a2[0]}
```

**This is original answer and is for LINKLIST**

Your error states:

> The field 'details.actionMap' has been declared as LINKMAP but the value is not a record or a record-id

You are trying to store a value into a field that is supposed to store references

According to orientDB [docs](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Insert.html)

You store references like this:

```
INSERT INTO Profiles SET name = 'Luca', friends = [#10:3, #10:4]
```

or with `SELECT` sub-querie:

```
INSERT INTO Diver SET name = 'Luca', buddy = (SELECT FROM Diver 
          WHERE name = 'Marko')
```

That will make your code to be:

```
INSERT INTO details SET name = "INITIALIZE", actionMap =[(SELECT FROM action WHERE start IS NOT null),(SELECT FROM action WHERE stop IS NOT null)];
```

**Extra tip:**

If you crate your actions in the same time, then you can add `details` and those 2 `action` with one query:

```
INSERT INTO details SET name = "INITIALIZE", actionMap = [(INSERT INTO yourActionTable SET yourActionField = 'yourFirstAction'), (INSERT INTO yourActionTable SET yourActionField = 'YourSecondAction')]
```

Comment: When i use the above query i'm getting The field 'details.actionMap' has been declared as LINKMAP but an incompatible type is used. I cannot create the actions in this query because I might wanna use the actions in different places

Comment: Oh yes, this is for LINKLIST. My bad. Can you check if your sub-query returns a record and not a collection  `select from action where start is not null` and take a look at this [“value is not a record or a record-id” when passing batch variable to “set =” in update
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35516022/value-is-not-a-record-or-a-record-id-when-passing-batch-variable-to-set-in)

Comment: Its returning of type collection

Comment: have you tried the code added ? does it gives the same error? Is the collection returned by subquery of one element ?

Comment: Sorry, i can't stay up any longer. If you get the same error as your original one, you can do this `{"1": $a1[0][0], "2": $a2[0][0]}` in my code example... or `{"1":(SELECT...)[0], "2":(SELECT...)[0]}` in your original code... I think this will solve your problem.